# c# WebApi How to create rsa private and public key

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rsa

I am looking at this [article](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/), and it is very useful for securing your web Api application. My problem is I do not understand how to generate your own RSA keys, it does not say anywhere in the article how to generate keys. Can anyone explain, how to generate, I looked around on the net, but could not find any useful articles, also I tried using putty and was confused. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article itself, though it doesn't explain in the text, is actually doing it. If you look at the unit test:

```
[Test] public void RSAParameters() 
{   
    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();  
    var privateParameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);  
    var publicParameters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);   

    //Export private parameter XML representation of privateParameters  
    //object created above  
    Debug.WriteLine(rsa.ToXmlString(true));   

    //Export private parameter XML representation of publicParameters  
    //object created above  
    Debug.WriteLine(rsa.ToXmlString(false)); 
}
```

Instantiating a new `RSACryptoServiceProvider` will create a new key. The `ExportParameters` call will export the public and private keys (depending on the boolean parameter, see the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8z5e11b.aspx) as XML string. You can then use the `FromXmlString()` method to use those keys in the future.